# how to logout user joomla 2.5.8 RSForm pro

Tags: string, forms, joomla2.5, logout

DATA:
Joomla 2.5.8
Component: RSForm Pro

I need to logout user when fisnished a form.
I'm using this code into PHP script for $thankYouMessage string:

```
session_destroy(); //session is now over 
header( 'Location: http://www.mysite.com/index.php' ); // relink to a page, with user logged out
```

The session user finshed, but now this command scrit is immideatly execution, 'cose the Thank You Message disapears...
How can I do for real use string $thankYouMessage works fine?